# Who is using an included file?

Tags: bash, files

With 'fuser' I can see which process is using the file.
However any included file does not show with 'fuser'.

mainfile

```
#! /bin/bash
source subfile

SomethingInSubFile

sleep 60
exit 0
```

subfile

```
SomethingInSubFile(){
    echo "Just some text."
}
```

When I start 'mainfile' the following result is output from 'fuser':

```
root@thisbox:/tmp# fuser mainfile
/tmp/mainfile:       25560
root@thisbox:/tmp# fuser subfile
<nothing>
```

Reason for asking: In my situation I have many bash scripts with
a 'source subfile' line. Those script are being used on several
systems. I have built an automated installer script which
uses 'fuser' to see if somebody is using a file. Upon which the
script waits until the file is released before replacing it
with the newest version.
Unfortunately I can not check if the 'subfile' is in use.

Answer (score 0):

After that source function exits, nothing is using the subfile. The script runs in  the subshell spawned by the script and sourcing any file with function definition acts as if those  functions were typed into the subshell by keyboard. During the execution of source file function it will be used by the sub shell very briefly.

You may want to add sleep function to the sourced file to test for yourself